# Android - how can i onCreate launch the camera without crashing the apps?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, crash

I have this problem, from first activity window i am launching this second activity window where i need directly see the cam preview > take snap shot > show the preview on this activity window.

now, with this is the way i need to launch it (expected and correct way of user demand), but after taking the picture and coming back to this window then apps crash almost on that way.

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.picture);
      Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.capture_btn);
      //photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          //@Override
          //public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
              startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
         // }
      //});
  }
```

But this way it does not crash, in this way its wrong use case, cause then it becomes two button press for my apps.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {
  private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
  private static final int PIC_CROP = 0; 
  private ImageView imageView;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.picture);
      Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.capture_btn);
      photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          //@Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
              startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
          }
      });
  }

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }  
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  } 

}
```

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from your crash when the camera is launched without the button press?

Comment: `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { public void run() { ... your code here ...}}, 100);` i think you need to leave `onCreate` to use `startActivityForResult`